# getting error Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1f193686 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp, oracle19c

**>         I am getting exception after upgrading oracle11g to oracle19C, using hikari as connection pool and hibernate and spring boot. Please

> help.
> When using IN query with lower number of value list its working but with large numbers its giving error.
> Error Recieved:-**

```
WARN 2022-05-20 11:56:03,250 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] HikariPool-1 - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@40896e8e marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
          Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
            at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
            at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
            at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:316)
            at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:128)
            at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:315)
            at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:257)
            at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:177)
            at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:95)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:132)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:88)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:395)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:410)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:269)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:807)
            ... 148 common frames omitted
    WARN 2022-05-20 11:56:03,251 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
    ERROR 2022-05-20 11:56:03,251 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] IO Error: Connection reset
    DEBUG 2022-05-20 11:56:03,251 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] HikariPool-1 - Closing connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@40896e8e: (connection is broken)
    ERROR 2022-05-20 11:56:03,252 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] Application exception overridden by rollback exception
    org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
```